# How to pack Chrome extension with it settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to pack Chrome extension with extension settings ? I need to share some extension with colleagues of mine. Did not found a receipt. I know it is possible to just pack extension. But when it is unpacked it does not contain any predefined settings.

Comment: Did you write said extension?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible unless you modify the code (assuming its yours or have licence to do so). the code could detect a setting isnt yet set and default to your setting.

there are many ways to persist options, so I cant give a more detailed answer without more specifics.

as a note, if the extension uses chrome sync storage, its options atuomatically sync to all your chrome devices, but still cant be automatically shared with colleagues.